# Help with Infopath or JQuery - Need Conditional formating to work

Tags: infopath, jquery

I have already tried hiring someone with JQUERY experience, however that failed as JQUERY could not override InfoPath forms code rendering.

We have setup a simple sharepoint form, which contains 60-65 fields, which are single line, dates, multi select pick lists, dropdowns and person/group.
Here are main requirements:

1) By default, when a form is opened, not to display a set of questions and only display them if a checkbox has been selected (this will be 2 sections of 10 and 10 fields). Need rules against 2 different check box fields.

2) Based on 2 different DATE fields, if DATE1 < DATE2, ONLY then display next Field (so when form is open those fields that are dependent on date should automatically be hidden), which would be a multi select checkbox (this we have tried with the rules and rules dont kick in when the COnditional formating is used on date fields)

3) There will be a set of 10 questions in the group or so, depending on the response of some, we need to display or not display others

Can someone tell me how that's doable. Person who did Jquery said that he can't override code that's rendered by InfoPath and we can't get the conditional statements to work.

Answer (score 0):

You Can set rules with rule type is Actions on Info-path and hide show filed. Click [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-rules-f00de016-7b2d-4ef8-b168-26b7748c22a1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) to more details